# Counter in purrr's map* function family

Tags: r, for-loop, purrr

I often need some sort of counter / index value when applying loop-functions to vectors / list. When using basic loop functions, this index can be created by successively adding 1 to some initial value. Consider the following example:

```r
lets <- letters[1:5]

n = 0
for (le in lets){
  n = n+1
  print(paste(le,"has index",n))
}
#> [1] "a has index 1"
#> [1] "b has index 2"
#> [1] "c has index 3"
#> [1] "d has index 4"
#> [1] "e has index 5"
```

The only way I've been able to access such an index value with the loop-functions from the `purrr` package is using `map2`. Is there a more elegant way to do this using only `purrr::map()`?

```r
library(purrr)


map2(lets,1:length(lets),~paste(.x,"has index",.y))

#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a has index 1"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "b has index 2"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "c has index 3"
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> [1] "d has index 4"
#> 
#> [[5]]
#> [1] "e has index 5"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closest approximation of what you're looking for is `purrr::imap`, which is described in the documentation as

> short hand for `map2(x, names(x), ...)` if `x` has names, or `map2(x,
>   seq_along(x), ...)` if it does not.

The following code works:

```
lets <- letters[1:5]

purrr::imap(lets, ~print(paste(.x, "has index", .y)))
```

I'm assuming you are in fact trying to create a new object and store it in a new variable. If you are looking to show output (like in this example, where the result is a `print` to the console), you should use the equivalent function `iwalk` which returns its output invisibly.

Answer (score 4):

Try `imap`

```
lets <- letters[1:5]
purrr::imap(lets, ~paste(.x,"has index",.y))
#[[1]]
#[1] "a has index 1"

#[[2]]
#[1] "b has index 2"

#[[3]]
#[1] "c has index 3"

#[[4]]
#[1] "d has index 4"

#[[5]]
#[1] "e has index 5"
```

Note that `imap` will use the names of the elements of `.x` as `.y` argument if the elements are named. If you don't want that use `imap(unname(...), ...)` - thanks to @Moody_Mudskipper.

---

A `base R` approach could be

```
sprintf("%s has index %d", lets, seq_along(lets))
# [1] "a has index 1" "b has index 2" "c has index 3" "d has index 4" "e has index 5"
```

Comment: note  that  `imap` will use the name of the element as `.y` if the elements are named, in that case `unname` first!

Comment: Thanks for this answer! @A. Stam posted [the same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54179939/4139249) simultaneously. I've accepted his answer since it includes a reviling  excerpt from the docs (_and_ he has less rep).